# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown button and radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What's the logic for drop down button and radio button in twitter bootstrap ...I have seen only drop down menu in twitter bootstrap..Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Button Dropdowns:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- dropdown menu links -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what you are asking though in terms of radio buttons so I think you should read Bootstrap's Form documentation, available at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Comment: Hi there, got it thanks...                                          <label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1"></label>